# Proportion of Oxygen in a typical white dwarf

Tags: astrophysics, physical-chemistry, white-dwarfs, metallicity

What's the proportion of Oxygen in a typical white dwarf relative to the proportion of Carbon?

Comment: Astronomy SE might be better for this, but many of their folks are over here as well... It is actually a very important question since the cross section for conversion of carbon to oxygen is not well known.

Comment: See Table 1 [here](https://orbi.uliege.be/bitstream/2268/217948/1/Giammichele_et_al-2018-Nature.pdf). I learned of that paper [here](https://pubs.aip.org/physicstoday/Online/4578/The-surprising-chemistry-at-the-core-of-a-white).

Comment: I answered over on Astronomy, for whatever that is worth. It fits well with another question over there on white dwarf crystallization.